# How to reallocate a struct in c?

Tags: c

I'm trying to work with the patient struct to insert a date into it. I'm using an infinite loop every time it should reallocate a new space of struct to insert into it.

It's working for the first iteration, but the problem appears in the second iteration. It gives me a run time error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct patient {
    char name[100];
    int age;
    char infection_date[100];
    char patient_address[100];
    int hospital_id;
};

struct patient *patient_ptr;
// number of patients
int *number_of_patients = 0;

// max in a single hospital
int *max_in_hospital = 10;
int *max_in_hospital_cnt = 0;
int *hospital_ids = 1;

void storing(struct patient **patients, int *num_patients, int *max_in_hosp, int *max_in_hosp_cnt, int *hosp_ids)
{
    //add 1 to number of patients
    (*num_patients)++;
    //reallocate our pointer
    *patients = (struct patient*)realloc(*patients, (*num_patients) * sizeof(struct patient));

    printf("\nPatient name: ");
    char patient_name[100];
    scanf("%s", patient_name);

    //check if the patient is exist.
    for (int i = 0; i < (*num_patients); i++) {
        //if the patient exist return
        if (strcmp((*patients[i]).name, patient_name) == 0) {
            printf("\nSorry Patient is exist.\n");
            return;
        }
    }

    strcpy((*patients[(*num_patients)-1]).name , patient_name);
    printf("\nPatient age: ");
    int age;
    scanf("%d", &age);
    (*patients[(*num_patients)-1]).age = age;

    printf("\nPatient infection date: ");
    char date[100];
    scanf("%s", date);
    strcpy((*patients[(*num_patients)-1]).infection_date , date);

    printf("\nPatient patient address: ");
    char address[100];
    scanf("%s", address);
    strcpy((*patients[(*num_patients)-1]).patient_address, address);

    printf("\nThe hospital id that the user will go to it is: %d\n", *hosp_ids);
    if ((*max_in_hosp_cnt) % (*max_in_hosp) == 0) {
        (*hosp_ids)++;
    }
    printf("\nPatient Added.\n");
}

int main()
{
    while (1) {
        storing(&patient_ptr, &number_of_patients, &max_in_hospital, &max_in_hospital_cnt, &hospital_ids);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `*patients[i]` is `*(patients[i])`, did you mean to do `(*patients)[i]`?

Comment: no sir it doesn't working, please take a copy of my code and try to fix it my deadline is today and i did all what i can but nothing working.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What run-time error are you getting?  Do not cast the return value from `malloc()` or `realloc()`.  It's not necessary in C and it can cause problems.

Comment: The variable `number_of_patients` is declared as a pointer, but it is used as an integer. It'll be better to have `int number_of_patients = 0;`. The same for `max_in_hospital `, `max_in_hospital_cnt ` and `hospital_ids `.

Comment: @Ehab Set a breakpoint on `*patients[i]` and watch the values. Then re-read the first comment.

Comment: @Joël Hecht
 i try it and it gives me the same error.

Comment: you make the `*patients[x]` mistake several times

Comment: @dxiv 
 No the problem wan not with it. when i comment the for loop part nothing change and it gives me the error again.

Comment: @M.M 
How? can you fix these errors?

Comment: Please [edit] you question and post the run time error(s) you get. We do not have necessarily the same development and run-time environment like you. BTW, what is it? -- I just formatted your source to make it more readable. But you need to invest some minutes to let us help you. If you have new source code, add it, please don't replace the old one because others refer to it.

Comment: @the busybee 
i'm not allowed to put images right now, but i think that the error is the ```*patient``` failed to reallocate.

Comment: Couple of notes: if your dataset it large, you benefit from making `patient` `name, infection_date` and `patient_address` pointers as well an allocating storge exactly. (you can use fixed buffers of whatever size you like to read the information, but allocate and store based on the exact length) Avoid the use of global variables, there is no need here. You allocate (`realloc`) in `storing`, but make the return `void` providing no way to indicate success/failure through the return.

Comment: @David C. Rankin
 i'm trying to make it return ```struct patient*``` but nothing changed.

Comment: You are thinking correctly. You can declare `struct patient *patient_ptr;` in `main()` and change the return type of `storing` to `struct patient *` (and remove the parameter for `patients`). Then declare `struct *patients;` in `storing` and `return patients;` at the end (or `NULL` on failure). In `main()`, you simply do `patient_ptr = storing (....)` and then check `if (patient_ptr != NULL) { /* you have a good pointer */ }` (looks like @Mohith is still working on his answer for you)

Comment: @david C.Rankin thank you, i will try it also but Mohith answer works for me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refresh your concepts on pointers. I did nothing spectacular than just removing `*` at few places. I am unsure whether your code is behaving as you expect, but at least for now, no compiler warnings and run time errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct patient {
    char name[100];
    int age;
    char infection_date[100];
    char patient_address[100];
    int hospital_id;
};

struct patient *patient_ptr = NULL;
// number of patients
int number_of_patients = 0;

// max in a single hospital
int max_in_hospital = 1;
int max_in_hospital_cnt = 0;
int hospital_ids = 1;

void storing(struct patient **_patients, int *num_patients, int *max_in_hosp, int *max_in_hosp_cnt, int *hosp_ids)
{
    //add 1 to number of patients
    (*num_patients)++;
    //reallocate our pointer
    *_patients = (struct patient*)realloc(*_patients, (*num_patients) * sizeof(struct patient));
    struct patient* patients = *_patients;

    printf("\nPatient name: ");
    char patient_name[100];
    scanf("%s", patient_name);

    //check if the patient is exist.
    for (int i = 0; i < (*num_patients); i++) {
        //if the patient exist return
        if (strcmp((patients[i]).name, patient_name) == 0) {
            printf("\nSorry Patient is exist.\n");
            return;
        }
    }

    strcpy((patients[(*num_patients)-1]).name , patient_name);
    printf("\nPatient age: ");
    int age;
    scanf("%d", &age);
    (patients[(*num_patients)-1]).age = age;

    printf("\nPatient infection date: ");
    char date[100];
    scanf("%s", date);
    strcpy((patients[(*num_patients)-1]).infection_date , date);

    printf("\nPatient patient address: ");
    char address[100];
    scanf("%s", address);
    strcpy((patients[(*num_patients)-1]).patient_address, address);

    printf("\nThe hospital id that the user will go to it is: %d\n", *hosp_ids);
    if ((*max_in_hosp_cnt) % (*max_in_hosp) == 0) {
        (*hosp_ids)++;
    }
    printf("\nPatient Added.\n");
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 3) {
        storing(&patient_ptr, &number_of_patients, &max_in_hospital, &max_in_hospital_cnt, &hospital_ids);
        i++;
    }

    int j = 0;
    while (j < 3) {
        printf("%s\n", patient_ptr[j].name);
        j++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Terminal Session:

```
Patient name: 1

Patient age: 1

Patient infection date: 1

Patient patient address: 1

The hospital id that the user will go to it is: 1

Patient Added.

Patient name: 2

Patient age: 2

Patient infection date: 2

Patient patient address: 2

The hospital id that the user will go to it is: 2

Patient Added.

Patient name: 3

Patient age: 3

Patient infection date: 3

Patient patient address: 3

The hospital id that the user will go to it is: 3

Patient Added.
1
2
3
```

A suggestion, you may probably want to check the patient presence before reallocating the memory for a new one because if the patient is present, the allocated memory goes uninitialized.

Comment: thank you it's working but i don't understand why it not working without creating a local pointer and then make the global pointer take it as a value.

Comment: @MohamedGK You can show me the code uploaded somewhere like pastebin.com , So I would understand your problem better

Comment: i'm sorry i can't do that now, the source code is secret right now. but big thanks, you solve the problem for me.